# Save xml api as and excel file in php

Tags: php, excel, xml

I have this code which save xml api as an xlsx. But When I save it, i can not open on computer. But txt doc and other formats support it. How can I save it as an xlsx file successfully.

```
<?php
$xlsx = file_get_contents("http://cbu.uz/uzc/arkhiv-kursov-valyut/xml/");
file_put_contents("currency/kurs.xlsx", $xlsx);
?>
```

Comment: Just to make this more clear. That url gives you an `xml` response `Content-Type: text/xml`..so here you have an `xml` string on your `$xlsx` variable...there is no straight way to convert an `xml` string into `php`, you need to add extra code in order to provide that functionality.  You can also use a librery like http://faisalman.github.io/simple-excel-php/api/0.3/

Comment: I can download xml as an excel file but cannot open it on computer. it gives me error. How can I fix it?